# Deleting connected objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a User class which `has_many` Addresses - and Address `belongs_to` User.
How do I define it so that when an address is deleted it gets removed from `user.adresses` too and vice versa, if I do `user.addresses.delete(address)`, then it is no longer appears in `Addresses.all`?

Answer (score 1):

To destroy addresses when a user is deleted, you can declare it on the association.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :addresses, :dependent => :destroy #destroy addresses when user destroyed
end
```

You don't need to do anything for the other way around, since the foreign key is on the `Address` model.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass :dependent => :destroy in the has_many realtionship of the User model

```
has_many :addresses, :dependent => :destroy
```

If you do this then, if a user is deleted then all the Address objects associated with this User will also be deleted.